# Unable to send a list as multiple texts through applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a code that sends a body of text where each word is sent as an iMessage. This is what I have so far:

```
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select file:" of type {"txt"})
set fileContents to paragraphs of (read theFile)
repeat with ln in fileContents
    tell application "Messages"

        set myid to get id of first service

        set theBuddy to buddy "phonenumber" of service id myid

        send fileContents to theBuddy
    end tell
end repeat
```

Error:

> Messages got an error: Can’t make {"Testing 1", "Testing 2"} into type
>   text, file or constant.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am thinking you are wanting to send an individual paragraph `ln` instead of the `fileContents` list.

Comment: You are aware of how thoroughly annoying this might be to the recipient, right?